# USBDLM and VLC video play

Tags: usb, video, vlc-media-player, autoplay

I've got a video hosted on a USB stick, that when I plug into a windows computer, the very helpful USBDLM tool automatically opens the video with VLC and some launch commands.

The issue I have is when the file is executed this way, VLC throws the following error:

```
VLC is unable to open the MRL 'file:///K:/System%20Volume%20Information/WPSettings.dat
```

While I can hide this, it causes playback issues with the video looping.

When I manually run the file off the USB drive, it runs and loops smoothly. When I create a basic batch script to run off the USB drive, it also runs with no problem.

Here's the USBDLM script piece:

```
[OnArrival]
FileExists=%Drive%\video\*.mp4
open="%ProgramFiles%\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe" %Root% -f --quiet --no-video-title --qt-start-minimized
```

What about the way that USBDLM executes the autorun is causing a problem? Why is it searching for WPSettings.dat on the USB drive?

I've searched the documentation and wondering if it is something to do with admin privileges?
https://www.uwe-sieber.de/usbdlm_help_e.html#config

Comment: Never got to the bottom of this but for a smooth autoplay solution, I ended up adding a VLC playlist file to startup folder, the XML video path pointing at the USB drive and setting video play settings manually inside VLC via tool menu. The letter is always the same thanks to USBDLM.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same thing happen when making a small signage system I found the only answer was to format the USB to NTFS.

I am guessing Windows puts extra filing info on fat32 and Fatex formats that VLC auto play doesn't like.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).